A puzzle for middle school students: cuboid or slice of cake?

A fixed volume of dough can be shaped into either a cuboid, or a slice of cake. Which shape should you choose, in order to minimize the total surface area of the dough?


Remarks:

The cuboid has six rectangular faces. If you choose the cuboid, you can choose the height, width and length, keeping the volume constant.
The slice of cake is a right prism whose base is a circular sector with a central angle less than 360°. If you choose the slice of cake, you can choose the height, radius and central angle, keeping the volume constant.
This is a puzzle for middle school students, so no differentiation. Pen and paper only.

Hint:

 Why is the area of a circle $\pi r^2$ ?


Answer:

 Both shapes give the same minimum surface area.

Explanation (thanks to the hint):

 Following the hint, we note that the sector of angle $\theta$ and radius $r$ can be rearranged into a rectangle of sides $r$ and $r\theta/2$. This follows from an analogue of the famous rearrangement construction to find the area of the circle using triangles as in the image below (source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle). The idea is to divide the sector into thin sectors and rearrange them into an approximate rectangle of the above mentioned sides. Middle schoolers are familiar with this construction too. 


 But then the two problems are identical, so they should give the same answer. (Note that the question didn’t ask us to find the minimum value of the surface area, just the shape that minimizes it.)


This is the idea I had also. Another way to think about it: If you think that "cuboid" is the answer to the question, then we can take the cuboid with minimum surface area, cut it up and rearrange the pieces into a slice of cake, and see that the slice of cake has the same total surface area as that cuboid, so cuboid is not the answer. And vice versa. Therefore the answer is that they have the same minimum surface area. (Notice that, in this approach, we don't even need to know any formulas for volume or surface area.)

I did not use a pen or a paper, but just typed the answer.
I guess that a middle school student can solve the problem as follows.
The final answer is under this spoiler:

 The same optimal value can be attained by both shapes.

The arguments:

 Let $V$ be the dough volume.


 Let $h$, $w$, and $\ell$ be the height, width, and length, of the cuboid respectively. Then $V=hw\ell$ and the total surface area $S$ of the dough is $2(hw+h\ell+wl)$. By the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means, $$S=2(hw+h\ell+w\ell)\ge 6\cdot\left(hw\cdot h\ell\cdot w\ell\right)^{1/3}=6V^{2/3},$$ and the equality is attained when $hw=h\ell=w\ell$, that is $h=w=\ell=V^{1/3}$. Then $S=6V^{2/3}$.


 Let $h$, $r$, and $\alpha$ be the height, radius, and central angle, of the slice. Then $V=\frac 12\alpha r^2h$ and the total surface area $S$ of the dough is $\alpha r^2+2rh+\alpha rh$. By the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means, $$S=\alpha r^2+2rh+\alpha rh\ge 3\left(\alpha r^2\cdot 2rh\cdot \alpha rh\right)^{1/3}=6\left(V^2\right)^{1/3},$$ and the equality is attained when $\alpha r^2=2rh=\alpha rh$, that is $\alpha=2$ and $r=h$. Then $S=6V^{2/3}$ again.


Not bad, but there is a much simpler solution, which does not require the AM-GM inequality.

You may want to include a quick tl;dr of the final result at the beginning of your answer

@DanDan面 Done.${}$

For both the cuboid and cake-slice, we have

 $S = 2A + Ph$, where $S, A, P, h$ are surface area, area of the top face, perimeter of the top face, and height, respectively.


 Since the total volume is simply $Ah$, $A$ and $h$ vary identically for both the cuboid and the cake slice. If we seek to minimize $S$, our best bet is to minimize $P$ for each possible value of $A$.
 For the cuboid, $P = 2w + \frac{2A}{w}$, where w is the larger of the two sides. Letting $w' = \frac{w}{\sqrt A} - 1$, $\frac{P}{2\sqrt A} = 1+w' + \frac{1}{1+w'}$. $w' \geq 1$ makes the sum greater than $2$, and $w' < 1$ allows us to expand this as $1+w'+1-w'+(w'^2-w'^3)+(w'^4-w'^5)+\dots \geq 2$, so we have $P\geq 4\sqrt A$.
 For the cake slice, surprisingly, we also get $P = 2r+\frac{2A}{r}$! This means that we can apply the same arguments as above, and achieve the same bound of $P \geq 4\sqrt A$. This means that every combination of $A$ and $h$ gives the same minimum value of $S$, whether the cuboid or cake slice is chosen, and so the choice of shape is irrelevant.


I note that $2w + \frac{2A}{w}\ge 4\sqrt A$ by the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means.

That's correct, but Dan's response to your answer suggests that simply invoking AM-GM isn't appropriate for the question.

I guess Dan rather would mean that $2w+\frac{2A}w$ and $2r+\frac{2A}r$ have the same range, and so the same minimal value, and thus we do not need to apply AM-AG to conclude this.
